# Room LiveData onChange called too fast. Many Activities stacked atop

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-room

```
@Dao
public interface LibraryCoverContentDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM LibraryCoverContent where rush_id = :rush_id")
    LiveData<List<LibraryCoverContent>> getContentsFromRushID(String rush_id);

    @Query("DELETE FROM library_cover where rush_id = :rush_id")
    void deleteContentsFromRushID(String rush_id);

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insertCoverContents(LibraryCoverContent... contents);

}
```

I want to open another activity once a list LiveData> mLibraryCoverContents is not null.

I am inserting the items downloaded from a retrofit call one by one into the room database, so apparently, my startActivity() call for the next activity happens many a times and multiple-same activities are opened over this activity.

I want only a single activity on top by calling onChanged only after all items of the retrofit call are inserted into db.

Please see the following related code for reference:

```
public void openReadRushScreen(final int index) {
        int count = mCoversList.size();
        if(count > index){
            mRushIDContent = mLibraryContentRepository.getContentsFromID(mCoversList.get(index).getRush_id());
            mRushIDContent.observe(this, new Observer<List<LibraryCoverContent>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<LibraryCoverContent> libraryCoverContents) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ON CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(libraryCoverContents!=null && libraryCoverContents.size()>0){
                        mRushIDContentsList = libraryCoverContents;
                        if(mRushIDContentsList.size()>0 && mRushIDContentsList.get(0).getRush_id().equals(mCoversList.get(index).getRush_id())){
                            mRushIDContentsList = new ArrayList<>();
                            startActivity(ReadRushActivity.getStartIntent(getActivity(), mCoversList.get(index).getRush_id(),
                                    mCoversList.get(index).isRush_audio(),
                                    mCoversList.get(index).getTitle()));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(mCoversList!=null && mCoversList.size()>index) getContent(mCoversList.get(index).getRush_id());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Empty Cover", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

---

```
public void getContent(String mRushId) {
        mApiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<Content>> call = mApiService.getRushContent(mRushId);
        if(call!=null){
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Content>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Content>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Content>> response) {
                    mContents = response.body();
                    if(mContents!=null && mContents.size()>0){
                        //noinspection ConstantConditions
                        List<LibraryCoverContent> coverContent = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int i=0; i<mContents.size(); i++){
                            coverContent.add(new LibraryCoverContent
                                    (mContents.get(i).getContent_id(), mContents.get(i).getRush_id(),
                                            mContents.get(i).getContent(), mContents.get(i).getAttr(),
                                            mContents.get(i).getDatetime(), mContents.get(i).getPage_no()));
                        }
                        mLibraryContentRepository.insertContentItems(coverContent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Content>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
//                    if(getActivity()!=null) Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Error while downloading rush content", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

---

```
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public void insertContentItems(final List<LibraryCoverContent> items) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
                    mLibraryCoverContentDao.insertCoverContents(items.get(i));
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: what version of [@Insert](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html#convenience-insert) are you using?

Comment: @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE) I am using to insert LibraryCoverContent db item. My room version is 1.0.0 , if thats what you're asking.

Comment: `"If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List<Long> instead."` so what parameter(s) does your method receive?

Comment: I have added the LibraryCoverContentDao for your reference. My @Insert method is a variadic function that i am using to insert item one at a time. My LibraryContentRepository method takes a list of LibraryCoverContent items and inserts each item separately to LibraryCoverContentDao method.

Comment: so do not insert it separately - did you read the quote from my previous comment?

Comment: I don't know how to insert all items at once in the room DAO.

Comment: `"If the parameter is an array or a collection, [...]"` did you read carefully the quote from my previous comment?

Comment: Thank you. I thought we couldn't pass lists as parameters to insert into room database, which we can.